# PCI_GET_DEVICE return NULL

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, pci, pci-e

I am writing a simple module for PCI devices `pci_get_device` return nothing when it is called

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/pci.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("ME");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple example Linux module.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

#define VENDOR_ID     0x8086
#define DEVICE_ID     0x8d10
#define BAR           0       
static struct pci_dev *dev = NULL;

static int __init lkm_example_init(void) {
    dev= pci_get_device(VENDOR_ID , DEVICE_ID , dev);
    if (dev == NULL) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Device Not found !\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // code
    return 0;
}

static void __exit lkm_example_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "EXIT KERNEL!\n");
}

module_init(lkm_example_init);
module_exit(lkm_example_exit);
```

I already got the `VENDOR_ID` and the  `DEVICE_ID`
from  `lspci -nn`
but I do know why I can not detect them with the module running

Comment: Shouldn't `dev` be set to `NULL` before calling `pci_get_device`?

Comment: I set it to NUL and nothing changed

Comment: Is pci root a device? I think it is a bus.

Comment: I do not see any proof that that device exists. Append the output of `lspci -nk -vv -d 8086:8d10`.